# Mute other media applications

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android media player application. I want to mute all media applications and just my player plays a sound. But i didn't find any way to solve my problem.

Could you please give me the solution?

Comment: please reformat your question

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Apps that behave nicely should pause their playback when they lose audio focus - but they're not required to do so.

Comment: is that so? but in the built in andriod player stops the built-in FM radio when it started playing and vice versa

Comment: They might be able to do so, because they are from the same developer. Perhaps they share the same playback background service, so that they will be able to stop each other.

Comment: ok , thx  , is there any way to pause those apps while am playing my app?

Comment: Some players might listen to `HEADSET_PLUG` broadcasts and stop playback if you broadcast that action saying that the headset has been unplugged. But this is kind of hackish and could lead to unwanted side-effects.

Comment: Hi All , 

    Am developing a media player in android , i want to add equalizer for that player , i can create the equalizer .

can you any1 tell me pls how can I assign the preset value to the sons and play it?

Comment: Please post a new question as your equalizer question has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: i cant create a question , its says it doesn't meet our quality standards